# How do I grab part of a URL string and make it display as text in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, url

Say I have a URL like "www.example.com/example.html?storeid=1400&shopperid=1200" and I want to pull the information for what shopperid equals, so in this example it would be 1200.I added this script into the header added   to the html. Why would this not be working?

JS:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var shopperid = getParameterByName('shopperid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL isn't formatted correctly. You have two ?, the second should be &.

"www.example.com/example.html?storeid=1400?shopperid=1200"

to:

"www.example.com/example.html?storeid=1400&shopperid=1200"

Comment: If you can't spot the different, he used an ampersand for the second GET parameter instead of a question mark which is to split the first param from the filename

Comment: Ok thanks so assuming URL is formatted correctly then the code itself should work by simply adding a <div id="shopperid"> </div> into the html, correct?

Comment: Huh? The code has nothing to do with that tag element. It just sets the shopperid to equal to the value of the shopperid parameter in the query string of the URL. You can place a alert(shopperid) or console.log it to verify.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not asking the right question. I just want to grab that shopperid from the URL and display it on the page in plain text. I thought that by simply adding that div tag that I would be able to achieve that. I'm obviously missing an important element so I apologize, I'm fairly new at this.

Comment: You would need that element and this JavaScript code: document.getElementById('shopperid').innerHTML = shopperid;

Comment: You can create a div, then get the div via JavaScript using getElementByID.  You will want to look that up.  Once you have a reference to the div in your JavaScript, you will set the html using innerHTML and the variable you stored the shopperID